# Logically zooming in/out in canvas

Tags: python-2.7, canvas, tkinter

I want to create one canvas widget, which allows user to draw on it. I am using canvas.bind for it. What I want is the size of canvas should be 32x32 originally, but when it is displayed, it should be like zoomed version of original widget, without resizing the original canvas. I have to use smaller size ( 32x32 ) for further processing on the drawn picture. Meaning if canvas size is 32x32 then it should be displayed as 512x512 size for drawing purpose , but 32x32 size for processing purpose. I tried with canvas.Scale but it seems that it will not be helpful for this purpose because it resizes original widget. Can someone please guide me? I use python2.7.

Thanks!

Comment: Dear @user2566909 if you think the posted answer solved your problem or at least it was a useful clue to find the solution you were looking for, please don't hesitate to accept it. If you don't know how to accept an answer, here you can find more information about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I completely understand your problem, then I think this would be your solution:

[image]

```
from __future__ import division
import Tkinter

ORIGINAL_WIDTH  = 32
ORIGINAL_HEIGHT = 32
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 512
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 512
WIDTH_RATIO  = WINDOW_WIDTH/ORIGINAL_WIDTH
HEIGHT_RATIO = WINDOW_HEIGHT/ORIGINAL_HEIGHT

class App(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = canvas = Tkinter.Canvas( self,
                                               highlightthickness = 0,
                                               width  = WINDOW_WIDTH,
                                               height = WINDOW_HEIGHT )
        self.canvas.pack()
        # Create a list for holding canvas objects
        self.scene = []
        # Draw objects and scale them
        self.draw()
        self.zoom()


    def draw(self):
        canvas = self.canvas

        # Draw rectangles within the range of 0..32 x 0..32
        rect1 = canvas.create_rectangle(  2,  0, 30,  2, fill='black' )
        rect2 = canvas.create_rectangle(  0,  2,  2, 30, fill='black' )
        rect3 = canvas.create_rectangle( 30,  2, 32, 30, fill='black' )
        rect4 = canvas.create_rectangle(  2, 30, 30, 32, fill='black' )
        rect5 = canvas.create_rectangle( 10, 10, 22, 22, fill='black' )

        self.scene.extend( (rect1, rect2, rect3, rect4, rect5) )

    def zoom(self):
        canvas = self.canvas
        # Scale all objects on scene
        for item in self.scene:
            canvas.scale( item, 0, 0, WIDTH_RATIO, HEIGHT_RATIO )

App().mainloop()
```